# Eagle connections glitch

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

I'm having trouble with connections in Eagle 7.6. I'm designing an LED board consisting over 300 UV and red LEDs. All of them connected in series of 3 + a 91ohm resistor and those series are connected in parallel. In schematic, everything looks fine, but once I've placed all of the components on the board, I began noticing some connection issues. Some connections appear that shouldn't be there (and yes, I triple checked the schematic). I've uploaded my whole project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2wRQ2r2rQGhcHM1RVhMOXNVVTQ/view?usp=sharing). 
Some of the invalid (?) connections: R217-R104; R188-R75.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: We do engineering here, not hand waving.

Comment: Could you engineer me a solution to my problem, then?

Comment: Not without a proper problem statement.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about, @Justin , R217 IS connected to R104 according to the schematic. Same with R188 and R75. Look at the wire that connects all along the bottom of the sheet then up each column.

Comment: See: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Expecting people to look over your project without formatting a good question makes this a bad question. Please ask specific questions Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your project, there actually is no error!

In your schematic, the right terminals of each resistor is connected to GND. In the schematic, this is done by clean wires running down each column, and an additional, horizontal  wire at the bottom.

But that's not how airwires in the board editor work. Here, each terminal is directly connected to the next terminal of the same net. And this "additional connections" you see are the connections from one column to the next:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I see it now that you highlighted the connections. After auto-routing, everything seems clean and pattern-like.

Comment: @Justin - Auto-routing is usually not the best solution. The human mind is a lot smarter then a program.  ;)

Comment: I think at this point the program is smarter. And I also wasn't very keen on routing over 600 components by hand...

Comment: As a semi-automatic approach, you could have wired the common signals GND and V_Red and V_UV, and let the autorouter do the rest. He only has to do straight, horizontal wires then.